# Approximate th Probability of a Sum of 16 Independent Uniform R.V.s

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

This question has to do with the Central Limit Theorem, uniform random variables, and cumulative distribution functions, I believe, but I'm not quite sure how to apply them all in the proper way.

Q: Approximate the probability that the sum of 16 independent uniform (0, 1) random variables exceeds 10.

Sample size = 10

I suppose I want P( Z > 10), where we use a CDF here.

In my class I was given an example of this, but in that example we were given the standard deviation (which was divided by the square root of the sample size). However, I'm not sure how to apply it in this case. A google search didn't give me the answer I wanted, so I'm hoping someone here can clarify.

TL;DR: How can I apply the central limit theorem here to solve this particular problem?

Comment: A random variable with a uniform distribution has a standard deviation equal to the difference between the maximum and the minimum, divided by $\sqrt{12}$.  Will that set you on your way?

Comment: In this case the minimum and maximum would refer to the individual values before they're summed up? As in, (0, 1)? Can you clarify where you obtained the sq-root of 12 from?

Comment: I assume you are to use a Normal Distribution Approximation for $Y=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_{16}.$    Then $\mu=E[Y]=16(0.5)=8.$   By indenpendence you $Var(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^{16}  Var(X_i) = 16 (1/12) = 4/3.$  Then by CLT, you have $Z=\frac{Y-8}{\sqrt{4/3}} \sim N(0,1)$  (approximately).   Note the exact distribution is the Iwrwin-Hall Distribution,

Comment: Can you explain that relation between the mean and the expected value? I'm not quite getting it there. In the book, we're given (Total sum - [mean*sample size]) / (standard deviation * sqroot(sample size))

Comment: @SuperRhinocerus: Yes, in this case, it would be $(1-0)/\sqrt{12}$.  The variance of a random variable $X$ is given by (among other expressions) $\sigma^2 = E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$.  For your random variables, the expected value $E(X)$ is obviously $1/2$, and the square of that is $1/4$.  The expected value of the square is given by the integral $\int_{x=0}^1 x^2 \, dx = x^3/3]_{x=0}^1 = 1/3$, so the variance is $\sigma^2 = 1/3 - 1/4 = 1/12$.  The standard deviation is the square root of the variance, or $\sigma = 1/\sqrt{12}$.

Comment: @mattbiesecker: I don't know whether to be pleased or chagrined to learn that there's a specific name for this distribution.  Pleased to find that someone decided to assign a name to something that seems pretty trivial, or chagrined that someone else got their name assigned to something that seems pretty trivial. :-)

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Can anyone confirm if the answer is .9582? I'm not sure if I carried out the rest of the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this was ever totally resolved. It is a question
that raises a number of basic issues.

Following the terminology of @mattbiesecker,
Let $Y = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots X_{16},$ where $X_i$ are
a random sample from $Unif(0,1).$
Then
$$E(Y) = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + \cdots + E(X_{16}) = 16(1/2) = 8$$
and, by independence,
$$V(Y) = V(X_1) + V(X_2) + \cdots + V(X_{16}) = 16(1/12) = 4/3.$$
Then, by the CLT, $Y$ is very nearly $N(\mu=8,\sigma^2=4/3),$
and so $\frac{Y - 8}{\sqrt{4/3}}$ is approximately standard normal.

Thus

$$P(Y > 10) \approx P\left(Z = \frac{Y-8}{\sqrt{4/3}} > \frac{10-8}{\sqrt{4/3}} = \sqrt{3}\right),$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1),$ standard normal.

Finally, from normal tables or software, 
$$P(Z > \sqrt{3}) = 1 - P(Z \le \sqrt{3}) \approx  0.0416.$$

*Notes:*

(1) For a random variable $Y,$ *mean* and *expectation* are alternate
terminologies for $E(Y).$

(2) The approximation in your question is quite good. Before modern methods using
transcendal functions were computationally convenient, it was customary
to simulate a random standard normal variable by adding 12 independent standard uniform random variables and subtracting 6.
[Pseudorandom generators usually produce results 'practically' indistinguishable from random $Unif(0,1).$]

(3) In a million simulated performances of your exact experiment (adding 16 independent
standard uniforms), the fraction of sums exceeding 10 was  0.041369.
Unlike the CLT, approximation by simulation can be done to almost any
desired degree of accuracy by increasing the number of iterations.

(4) Generally, in 'favorable circumstances' (where a moderate number of independent random variables
from a symmetrical distribution without 'fat' tails are summed or averaged), one
can expect 2 or 3-place accuracy from an approximation based on the CLT.

(5) If any part of the main derivation above these 'notes' remains unclear, please leave a specific Comment below, and I (or someone else) will try to help.

Comment: It was resolved, but no answer was actually given if that makes sense.